# Why is the `open()` function expecting a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Im trying to open and read a number of files so that I can search through and, extract parts of them using some regular expressions. However, I cannot get Python/PyCharm to open the files

The folder containing the files is in the Interpreter's `PATH` list. Initially the error was `(PATH that I passed) DOES NOT EXIST`. So, I added the first file itself to the Interpreter's `PATH` list. Now it raises a different error, that `PATH` does not lead to a directory

```py
  stack = os.listdir(
  "/Users/gregorytaylor/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries"
)

for entry in stack:

  # opens and reads file within `contents` variable
file_path = (
     "/Users/gregorytaylor/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries" + "/" + entry + "/"

  )

  selection = open(file_path, "rt")
  contents = read(selection)
```

This is the error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/../PycharmProjects/eu4_country_text_extraction/venv/completed_code", line 34, in <module>
    selection = open(file_path, "rt")
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/../Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries/TRI - Trier.txt/'
```

Am I making a mistake in my function selection or passing the arguments? Stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray `/` in the path you try to open. A file can't have one at the end, so just remove it.

By the way, The `PATH` variable does not have anything to do with opening a file, you don't have to set it.

Comment: Thank You! Q:WHY IS OPEN() EXPECTING A DIRECTORY??? A:BECAUSE YOU TOLD IT TO DO SO lolol. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: btw, is the PATH then only for files I want to import as modules?

Comment: PATH is where your operating system looks for executables (like the python executable , for instance). When importing modules, python will look in your current directory + the contents of your PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can view the latter by `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't stress yourself over building your own paths. There's a builtin module that can do it for you and is platform independent (it will work on Windows, Linux, and Mac)

Instead of doing `file_path = "/Users/randomfolder" + "/" + entry + "/"`, import `os` and use the `os.path.join` method. (And as mentioned in the other answer, the problem is the final "/" you add at the end)

```py
import os

root_path = "/Users/gregorytaylor/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries" 
stack = os.listdir(root_path)

for entry in stack:
  # opens and reads file within `contents` variable
  file_path = os.path.join(root_path, entry)  # <-- Will properly format the path
  if not os.path.isfile(file_path): # Skip anything that isn't a file
    continue # Continue will jump to the top of the loop and begin the next iteration
  selection = open(file_path, "rt")
  contents = read(selection)
```

Comment: This is excellent info, thank you. So you only have to declare the full path once, inside `root_path` and then it can be referenced/used with the os.path.join function as you showed above?

Comment: Yes. You may also want to add a check to make sure `file_path` is a file and not another directory. `os.listdir` will give you a list of everything inside that folder, including any other folders. I've edited that check into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- First, use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) not `os`, for which there are many reasons [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

### Code with `exception` handling

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/Users/gregorytaylor/Documents/software_development/my_python_code/random/countries')

for entry in stack:
    f_p = p / entry  # entry is a file name in stack; add entry to path p
    print(f_p)  # if you want to see what you're opening
    if f_p.is_file():  # checks that you've provide a file and not a path
        try:
            with f_p.open('rt') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                print(contents)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```